# Resize a javascript banner ad

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am supposed to put an ad on the side panel of our website, The ad is actually a piece of javascript that is provided by PayPal. This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-pp-pubid="xxxxxxx" data-pp-placementtype="190x100"> (function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script>
```

The problem is we don't have a space on the site that fits the dimensions of any of their offered banners. The one above is the closest, but I need it to be 10px wider. You cannot just change the size in the script, it will not display if you do, I assume something on the PayPal end checks and if the script has been altered it won't display it.

I am thinking there must be a way to put this in a `<div>` or maybe a table and force the size to be 200px wide, but I can't seem to get either method to work. Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: if you manage to force the banner to be wider you realize the images are going to be stretched and out of proportion, right?

Comment: Why not just center it up and use an appropriate background color? You could even use 10px side borders to use multiple colors.

Comment: Would this violate any advertising terms? Not sure, but this might be something worth considering.

Comment: Henser: No it's close enough and the image is all text so it can be re sized safely without looking bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>[Found This Site](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.user-groups.linux.ilug.general/47427)</del> (Dead Link)

Which had the answer. I adapted it a little (and fixed a typo) but it indeed did the trick. I had been trying the same general idea with no success, must have been syntax or maybe just a poor understanding of some part of the CSS.

```
     <div id='paypal-banner'>
   <style  type='text/css'>
      div#paypal-banner img { width: 200px }
   </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-pp-pubid="xxxxxxxxxx" data-pp- placementtype="190x100"> (function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-pp-pubid="4bb40d075a" data-pp-placementtype="190x100">
(function (d, t) {"use strict";var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";s.parentNode.insertBefore(n,s);}(document, "script"));
</script>
```